# Restore an array from sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android

My app first of all call checkIndex(), if index is not null go to main screen.

I save an array to shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt(prog +"_size", prog.length);
for(int i=0;i<prog.length;i++)
editor.putString(prog + "_" + i, prog[i]);
editor.putInt("x", x);
editor.commit();
```

to callback array, I use this:

```
  int size = prefs.getInt(prog +"_size", 0);
  String prog2[] = new String[size];
  for(int i=0; i<prog2.length; i++) 
  prog2[i] = prefs.getString(prog + "_" + i, "");
  prog=prog2;  
  int l = prefs.getInt("x", 0);
  x=l;

  textView1.setText(""+prog[x]);
```

logcat:

```
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.example.perledisaggezza.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:428)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-01 00:53:35.976: E/AndroidRuntime(6222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what line is 428? is it `prog=prog2;`?

Comment: I've 4 array strings (prog1[],prog2[],prog3[],prog4[])

Comment: **always** use `{` and `}` for code blocks or you will be punished in less expected moment

Comment: an index, users choose (1,2,3,4) for each choice (prog=prog1 or prog2 or prog3 or prog4) next it show on textview array prog[x]

Comment: is there a reason why you can't simply save the String choices that the user has picked into the sharedPreferences, as opposed to the array and an index of it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give you a definite answer.  But looking at the second code segment there are two places where that exception might be thrown:

```
  int size = prefs.getInt(prog +"_size", 0);
  String prog2[] = new String[size];
  for(int i=0; i<prog2.length; i++) {
      prog2[i] = prefs.getString(prog + "_" + i, "");  // FIRST PLACE
  }
  prog=prog2;  
  int l = prefs.getInt("x", 0);
  x=l;

  textView1.setText(""+prog[x]);    // SECOND PLACE
```

The first place we can dismiss because `i` will always be less than `prog2.length`..

The second place is possible if the value of the "x" property is greater than the value of `size` ... which comes from a different property.

Looking at the other code fragment, there is nothing that ensures that the "x" property will be less than the size.  So at least this causation is plausible.